# C# Calculator using string

Tags: c#, string, char, calculator

I need to solve an arithmetic operation on a string line, also without using any library. I have tried the following code -

```cs
string s = Console.ReadLine();

switch (s[1])
{
    case s[1] == "+":
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] + s[2]));
        break;
    case "-":
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] - s[2]));
        break;
    case "*":
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] * s[2]));
        break;
    case "/":
        if (s[2] != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] / s[2]));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Indeterminate");
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

But I'm not sure how to convert string to char.

Is there any way to make this work? I'm looking for any advice or tip.

Comment: Parse to the type you want to operate on. If you try to add the characters '4' and '5' together for example (which you *can* do), you will get 105, not 9.

Comment: You should state what specifically isn't working. Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Convert the input string to the proper types first (i.e. get the first number, the operator, and the second number parsed into different variables). Also, what if someone entered `"10 + 3"`? Using an index on the string is not very flexible.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Don't forget to `Accept` an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jeroenh mentioned, the issue is that you're comparing a `char` to a `string` in the `switch` cases, which is not allowed. You must compare like types.

But also, it might be a good idea to parse the input string into the proper types first, and then do the comparison and mathematic operations, rather than relying on the index of a character in the string. This allows you to be more flexible on user input, in case they enter a multi-digit number, or add spaces around the operator.

For example:

```
// These are the allowed operators
var operators = new[] {'+', '-', '/', '*'};

// Get user input
string s = Console.ReadLine();

// Find the first index of an operator
var operatorIndex = operators.Any(s.Contains)
    ? operators.Select(op => s.IndexOf(op)).Where(index => index > -1).Min()
    : -1;

// If no valid operators are present, give an error message to the user
if (operatorIndex < 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(
        $"Input doesn't contain a valid operator ({string.Join(", ", operators)}).");
}

// Based on the operator position, find the portions of the string that
// represent the first number, the operator, and the second number.
var firstNumber = s.Substring(0, operatorIndex);
var operatorChar = s[operatorIndex];
var secondNumber = s.Substring(operatorIndex + 1);
        
int operand1, operand2;

// Try to parse the first and second number to integers. If either 
// of them are invalid, give an error message to the user
if (!int.TryParse(firstNumber, out operand1) ||
    !int.TryParse(secondNumber, out operand2))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(
        $"Input doesn't contain a valid integer on each side of the operator.");
}

// Now we can swich on the operator character and do math with the integers
switch (operatorChar)
{
    case '+':
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (operand1 + operand2));
        break;
    case '-':
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (operand1 - operand2));
        break;
    case '*':
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (operand1 * operand2));
        break;
    case '/':
        if (operand2 != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (operand1 / operand2));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Indeterminate");
        break;
}

Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Can't get to work "IndexOfFirst" on the string. Is there any solution or condition I need to be aware of? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ah, sorry! That was an extension method I had written long ago and forgot it wasn't part of the class!! I've updated the code with the extension method code inline so it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you the issue:

```
 CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'
```

This error occurs at the `case` statements. It expects a `char`, not a `string`. A string literal in C# is in double quotes, a character literal (char) is in single quotes.

In the first case statement, you have `s[1] == "+"`. There shouldn't be a comparison there (the `switch case` does that for you)

```
switch (s[1]) // s[1] is of type char 
{
    case '+': 
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] + s[2]));
        break;
    case '-':
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] - s[2]));
        break;
    case '*':
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] * s[2]));
        break;
    case '/':
        if (s[2] != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + (s[0] / s[2]));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Indeterminate");
        break;
}
```

Finally, you should note that character literal numbers have a different numeric value than their representation.  You should parse the character to get the numeric value. For example:

```
var value1 = int.Parse(s[0].ToString());
var value2 = int.Parse(s[2].ToString());
```

Next, you will realize that your calculator only supports 1-digit numbers, and you may want to add some input validation up front to avoid your program crashing on invalid input.

Comment: Also probably worth noting that mathematical operation on character probably isn't going to give OP the values they're looking for.

Comment: Also important to note the first case statement has an expression in it which evaluates incorrectly for your switch statement: `case s[1] == "+":`. You're already comparing against `s[1]` so there's no need to put it in the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

If the task doesn't exclude namespaces available in .Net you can adapt this fantastic example in the  [Microsoft DotNet Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#regular-expressions) to your needs.

Here is the snippet of the code they explain:

```cs
String[] expressions = {
 "16 + 21",
 "31 * 3", 
 "28 / 3",
 "42 - 18", 
 "12 * 7",
 "2, 4, 6, 8" };

String pattern = @"(\d+)\s+([-+*/])\s+(\d+)";

foreach (var expression in expressions)
  foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(expression, pattern)) 
  {
    int value1 = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
    int value2 = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value);
    switch (m.Groups[2].Value)
    {
      case "+":
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", m.Value, value1 + value2);
        break;
      case "-":
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", m.Value, value1 - value2);
        break;
      case "*":
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", m.Value, value1 * value2);
        break;
      case "/":
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1:N2}", m.Value, value1 / value2);
        break;
    }
  }
// The example displays the following output:
//       16 + 21 = 37
//       31 * 3 = 93
//       28 / 3 = 9.33
//       42 - 18 = 24
//       12 * 7 = 84
```

Using a regular expression you can "save" the sections of your original input string and break it apart into the matched values of an expression.

Here is an image of what the regular expression does:

[image: Regular Expression explained]

The regular expression breaks apart your string into a Capture Group of your first number (available via `m.Groups[1]` and saved into `value1`), a Capture Group for your operator into group 2 and a Capture Group of your second number into group 3.

Taking the `Console.ReadLine()` input and using regular expressions you can reach a similar result:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


//...

string expression = Console.ReadLine()

String pattern = @"(\d+)\s+([-+*/])\s+(\d+)";
 
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(expression, pattern)) 
{
  // As others have pointed out you need to parse your numbers:
  int value1 = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
  int value2 = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value);
  
  // Now we switch case the operator in Group 2
  switch (m.Groups[2].Value)
  {
    case "+":
      Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", m.Value, value1 + value2);
      break;
    case "-":
      Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", m.Value, value1 - value2);
      break;
    case "*":
      Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", m.Value, value1 * value2);
      break;
    case "/":
      Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1:N2}", m.Value, value1 / value2);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfurtunatly I can't use any namespace or libraries. But thanks so much for your time.